Nuxt3, lifecycle hooks and setup
Which way is better to use to call fetch requests? Call fetch request in lifecycle hooks (onBeforeMount, onMounted etc.) or just in setup like this


See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your intention is unknown. If you want to wait for all promises regardless of their result then yes, allSettled it is. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Depends on what you want as a behavior/UX. This might be a good start to understand a few things: https://youtu.be/b1S5os65Urs?t=280

@EstusFlask sry, for not correct question, I mean, that i can use allSettled both in lifecycle hooks and just in setup, which way is better may be u can help me find some articles on this topic

Give it a Google search rather.
